# How to make the systemprintln statement to print only the arraylist values without repeating the text

Tags: java, arraylist, println

How  to print only the arraylist values without repeating the highlighted text part

referred the solutions provided but looks complex, please provide a simple solution on how to print only the values

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DuplicateNuminArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String progLanguages[] = {"Java", "Python", "C", "C++", "Java", "C"};


        for (int i = 0; i < progLanguages.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < progLanguages.length; j++)
            {
                if(progLanguages[i].equals(progLanguages[j]))
                {   
                    System.out.println("The Duplicate string is :" +progLanguages[i]);

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

I expect the print statemenet to print only as below
The Duplicate string is :Java, C
instead of 
The Duplicate string is :Java
The Duplicate string is :C

Comment: I expect the print statement to print only as below                                                     The Duplicate string is :Java, C
instead of                                                                                                                  The Duplicate string is :Java                                                                                    
The Duplicate string is :C

Answer (score 2):

You would need to collect all of the duplicates in a data-structure (and preserve uniqueness). One such data-structure is the collection type `Set`. Something like,

```
String progLanguages[] = { "Java", "Python", "C", "C++", "Java", "C" };
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < progLanguages.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < progLanguages.length; j++) {
        if (progLanguages[i].equals(progLanguages[j])) {
            set.add(progLanguages[i]);
        }
    }
}
System.out.printf("The Duplicate string is: %s%n", set);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Elliott, this address my question, you've provided very good solution. Thanks a lot for your swift response. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I like Elliott's answer better, but an alternative answer is to use print instead of println. If you just move one print statement outside of the for loops and then just use print in side your if block instead of println you'll just append on the end all in line. Like so:

```
 String[] progLanguages = {"Java", "Python", "C", "C++", "Java", "C"};

        System.out.print("The Duplicate string is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < progLanguages.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < progLanguages.length; j++)
            {
                if(progLanguages[i].equals(progLanguages[j]))
                {
                    System.out.print(progLanguages[i] + " ");

                }
            }

        }
```

Or even look into StringBuilder

```
 StringBuilder myBuilder = new StringBuilder("The Duplicate String is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < progLanguages.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < progLanguages.length; j++)
        {
            if(progLanguages[i].equals(progLanguages[j]))
            {
                myBuilder.append(progLanguages[i]);
                myBuilder.append(" ");
            }
        }

    }
        System.out.println(myBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chas, this also helps me to solve this problem in different ways. Thank you for detail explanation.